# Is elementary OS 5.1.7 “Hera” supported on Intel 11th Gen Mobile Processors?

Tags: graphic-drivers, graphics, intel

I have a Huawei Matebook D15 laptop. Precise model is BOD-WWX9-PCB. It has latest 11th gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 CPU which comes with Intel Iris Xe graphics.

Main problem is - when I tried live-usb to check if necessary software (VMware Horizon client) for my job is working correctly, I connected to Host server and instead of seeing working environment I saw black screen.

I am not sure what can be the exact reason, but I am sure for the most part it's not VMware problem, because both Pop_OS! 21.04 and Fedora 34 live-usb worked with VMWare Horizon out of the box.

So what should I do? Should I try installing 5.1.7 and manually updating the kernel to latest or hope that 5.8 (or whatever it is) is elementary OS 6 will support latest intel graphics?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pop os uses the 5.11 kernel, fedora 34 kernel 5.12.
Try a manual update.
i did it for my dell to 5.14 and updated manually all missing firmware i915.
firmware package https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/

Comment: So my to-do list is following:
- install elementary OS 5.1.7 with kernel 5.4
- manually update it to 5.12-5.14
- install i915 drivers?

Thanks! I will try it as soon as I get back to my laptop

Comment: Yes when you will update the kernel (update-initramfs -u -k all) it will show up a list a problem missing /lib/firmware/i915/name_of_the_lib.bin so you have to download them and copy them in the root folder /lib/firmware/i915/lib.bin with the terminal with  sudo cp ~/Downloads/*.bin /lib/firmware/i915/
This is what I did from this site with only the ones I missed. If you have the complete folder, you open a terminal in the folder you downloaded and run the same command to copy them.
my elementary os hera is running with this kernel now that I am writing to you Linux 5.14.0-051400rc2-generic

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915
and kernel link
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/